# Gradient prefix not working properly with scss and compass

Tags: css, sass

I am currently new to scss and compass. I recently heard about it and trying to learn and work with my projects. However I am using command line to complile scss file.
I downloaded the compass source file from:

https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/stable/frameworks/compass

I am trying to use gradient through compass. I import the _images file to from compass folder and started working with gradient. It gives an output but the gradient are not working.
Here's my code for scss:

> @import "compass/css3/images";
>
> .testgradient { width:300px; height:300px; float:left;
>
> @include background(
>
> ```
>  linear-gradient(top left, #333, #0c0)
> ```
>
> );
>    }

css output:

```
.testgradient {
 width: 300px;  height: 300px;  float: left;
background: -owg(compact(linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
background: -webkit(compact(linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
background: -moz(compact(linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
background: -o(compact(linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
background: compact(linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false); }
```

As you can see in the output that prefix are not well defined. I tired of searching at Google please tell me if am doing wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have install ruby in my windows pc and install sass and compass through command line by typing following command.

```
 gem install compass
 gem install sass
```

I have used these two command to install compass and sass 
and to compile

```
sass --watch --style compressed path1:path2
```

Comment: What version of Compass are you using? I can't duplicate this problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't install it as a gem?  It looks like there is some other dependency that is missing.

Comment: Do you have an up to date version of Sass as well?  I think the current stable version is 3.2.3.

Comment: yea its sass 3.2.3. Can you tell me if the source file from github is broken or there is other compass source file to download to make it work.

Comment: Is there a reason you downloaded the source instead of installing the Compass gem?

Comment: can it be done only with compass gem. If yes i am unaware about it. Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey the problem is solved. The mistake is i was using sass compiler to compile

```
sass --watch --style compressed sass:css
```

It was actually

```
compass watch projectname
```

I am sorry if my question was unclear. Please no downvote.